# SQL long execution time

Tags: t-sql

This query works fine there is only one problem and that's his long execution time. Can someone show me some good optimizations and explain them.

```
  SELECT TOP 5 PC.PersonID, P.FirstName, P.LastName, P.A, COUNT(*) Together
    FROM PersonCheckIn PC

    INNER JOIN Person P ON P.PersonID = PC.PersonID

    WHERE CAST(CheckInDate AS DATE) IN (SELECT CAST(CheckInDate AS DATE)
                        FROM PersonCheckIn C    
                            WHERE C.PersonId = 20)  AND

                        PC.TimeTableID IN (SELECT CIn.TimeTableID
                        FROM PersonCheckIn CIn  
                            WHERE CIn.PersonId = 20)
    AND PC.PersonId <> 20  -- not count same person

    GROUP BY PC.PersonId, P.FirstName, P.LastName, P.A
    ORDER BY Together DESC;
```

Comment: At a very minimum you should [include the actual Execution Plan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7359705/1260204), you could use [Paste the Plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/) and share the link in your question. Also [try to read it yourself](https://stackoverflow.com/a/759097/1260204), maybe you can figure out the performance issue(s) with your query.  Finally include the [schema DDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) along with the query you are executing.

Comment: That order by is going to take a while if there are a lot of records. What happens when you remove the two derived tables? I agree with @Igor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Avoiding sub-queries and IN() Statement will drasticaly decrease execution time...

Even so `CheckInDate` is not prefixed with its table alias in your query (And we have to guess witch table is concerned :( ), maybe this will do the job :

```
SELECT TOP 5 PC.PersonID, P.FirstName, P.LastName, P.A, COUNT(*) Together
    FROM PersonCheckIn PC
    INNER JOIN Person P ON P.PersonID = PC.PersonID
    INNER JOIN PersonCheckIn LU ON (LU.PersonId = 20 AND PC.CheckInDate = LU.CheckInDate AND PC.TimeTableID = LU.TimeTableID)     
    WHERE PC.PersonId <> 20  -- not count same person
    GROUP BY PC.PersonId, P.FirstName, P.LastName, P.A
    ORDER BY Together DESC;
```

If not, please :
- set the missing alias.
- give use data structure.
- give us data exemple.
- give us expected result exemple.